# Mask out non-bare soil pixels in Landsat8

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-8

I aim to create an Landsat8 image for bare-soil (no vegetation). To do this, I plan to derive the quantile of the bare soil index for each pixel and mask out pixels where the bare soil index has a value lower than the 95th quantile.

I got until the point where I added the bare soil index to the imagecollection, and created an image of the 95th quantile of the bare soil index for each pixel. But how can I then use this as a mask?

```
//Imports (country borders and landsat8 collection)
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017"),
    L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2");

// Define a function to add BSI (bare soil index)
var addBSI = function(image){
  var bsi = image.expression(
    '((SWIR+RED)-(NIR+BLUE)) / ((SWIR+RED) + (NIR + BLUE))', {
      'RED': image.select('SR_B4'),
      'SWIR': image.select('SR_B7'),
      'NIR': image.select('SR_B5'),
      'BLUE': image.select('SR_B2')
    }).rename('BSI');
  return image.addBands(bsi);
};

// Create 'collection', filtering landsat collection and adding bare soil index
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(L8

  // filter images within range (2014-2022)
  .filterDate("2014-01-01", "2022-12-31")
  
  // incldue geographic filter on created shape
  .filterBounds(netherlands)
 
  //filter away  images with many clouds
  .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 10)
  
  //add bare soil index to collection
  .map(addBSI));

//Create image of 95th quantile of bare soil index
var bsi95 = collection.select('BSI').reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([95]))

//Mask out pixels where BSI is lower than the pixel-specific 95th quantile of the BSI
//?
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to mask the whole collection. You can address this issue by creating two functions. Function 1 adds the band bsi95 to each image. Function 2 creates the mask by specifying that BSI has to be lower than bsi95.
Add the following code below yours (scaling factors are not mandatory, but they help to better visualize the results):

```
// Apply scaling factors Just to better visualize results
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

var collection_scaled = collection.map(applyScaleFactors);

// Function to add bsi95 as a band to the whole collection
function createBand(img) {
  return img.addBands([bsi95]);
}

// Mask function 
var bsi_mask = function(image) {
  // Select BSI percentile 95  Band
  var bsi95 = image.select("BSI_p95");
  // Select BSI band
  var bsi = image.select("BSI");
  // Create mask (BSI lower than BSI95)
  var bsimask = bsi.lt(bsi95);
  image = image.updateMask(bsimask);
  // 
  return image.addBands(bsimask);
};

// Apply functions
var collection_masked = collection_scaled.map(createBand).map(bsi_mask);

// Let's visualize
var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

Map.addLayer(collection_scaled.first(), visualization, 'Original');
Map.addLayer(collection_masked.first(), visualization, 'Masked');
```